# SQL: Is this JOIN over a player table and a subquery-created high score table the best way to perform this operation?

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2014

I have a query the I believe (not fully tested, only sanity-checked) works, but seems incredibly overwrought to me.  It's a join over three tables.

One table is a quest table with questID, playerID, and score.  Another table is a player table that contains the territory the player is in. A third table is not a real table; it's a subquery that produces a temporary result that consists of the highest scoring player for each territory.

```
SELECT 
    Q1.QuestID, Q1.PersonID, C1.TerritoryID
FROM 
    [dbo].[T_QuestSys_Quest] AS Q1
JOIN 
    [GZ_GAME].[dbo].[T_Character] AS C1 ON Q1.PersonID = C1.PersonID
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         TerritoryID, MAX(Score) AS HighScore
     FROM 
         [GZ_GAME].[dbo].[T_QuestSys_Quest] AS Q2
     JOIN 
         [GZ_GAME].[dbo].[T_Character] AS C2 ON Q2.PersonID = C2.PersonID 
                                             AND Q2.QuestID = @QuestID
     GROUP BY 
         TerritoryID) AS S ON Q1.Score = S.HighScore 
                           AND C1.TerritoryID = S.TerritoryID 
                           AND Q1.QuestID = @QuestID
```

Notably, the subquery would not allow me add additional terms on the `SELECT` statement resulting in an error:

> invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause").

It seemed to me that the `MAX(Score)` would be sufficiently disambiguating as to which `PersonID` I wanted, but I guess not.

Anyway, my questions are: Is there a better way to do this in terms of elegance/simplicity?  Is there a better way to do this in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0):

One method use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT *,Rwo_number()OVER(partition BY territoryid ORDER BY score DESC) RN
         FROM   [GZ_GAME].[dbo].[t_questsys_quest] AS Q2 
                JOIN [GZ_GAME].[dbo].[t_character] AS C2 
                  ON Q2.personid = C2.personid 
                     AND Q2.questid = @QuestID) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1
```